# The history behind the broken epsilon

Tags: fonts, symbols

In LaTeX, there are two epsilons: `\varepsilon` and `\epsilon`.

[image]

When I see the second one used in mathematics texts, I consider it a typo, because the first one corresponds to what is used in the majority of texts but also what is used when writing maths by hand. By personal taste, I prefer the first one and consider it the correct version.

Be that as it may, whichever is the correct one, there seems to be no need to have two. Hence my question:

Why are there two versions or epsilons? Why does the command `\epsilon` not get compile into the first version?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\texttt{\textbackslash{}varepsilon}     & \(\varepsilon\)   \\
\texttt{\textbackslash{}epsilon}        &\(\epsilon\)           
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have really no idea what tags to use for this question so please, retag it with more suitable tags if possible.

Comment: [Related](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98013/varepsilon-vs-epsilon)?

Answer (score 6):

From Wikipedia:

> The lowercase version has two typographical variants, both inherited from medieval Greek handwriting. One, the most common in modern typography and inherited from medieval minuscule, looks like a reversed "3". The other, also known as lunate or uncial epsilon and inherited from earlier uncial writing,[1][2] looks like a semicircle crossed by a horizontal bar. While in normal typography these are just alternative font variants, they may have different meanings as mathematical symbols. Computer systems therefore offer distinct encodings for them.[1] In Unicode, the character U+03F5 "Greek lunate epsilon symbol" (ϵ) is provided specifically for the lunate form. In TeX, `\epsilon` (`\epsilon\!`) denotes the lunate form, while `\varepsilon` (`\varepsilon\!`) denotes the inverted-3 form.

---

Most math texts I saw use `\epsilon` but it is convenient at times to have a variant.

Comment: +1 for the wikipedia ref, If I may I'll add that to my answer over in the other question (as this question has been closed as duplicate)