# What is \varpi?

Tags: symbols, greek

I came across the symbol `\varpi` in a paper and had no idea how to pronounce it or even what alphabet it's from (I'm guessing Greek since it looks like lowercase omega).

Does anyone know how to pronounce this or where it originates from?

Here's what it looks like:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 4):

Okay, after a bit more searching, I found this post:

[What does the \var prefix stand for in \varphi and \varepsilon etc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304534/what-does-the-var-prefix-stand-for-in-varphi-and-varepsilon-etc)

So, I guess it's a variant of `\pi`. That post has more explanation of these variants and it's pretty interesting.

Comment: yes see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98018/1090

Comment: I suppose you mean the `dorian pi`, which looks like $\bar{\omega}$?

Comment: @Bernard yes there's an image in the question

Comment: @David Carlisle: Thanks  – I hadn't noticed it.