# What is this symbol that looks like an epsilon and \in symbol?

Tags: symbols

I came across this symbol that  looks like an epsilon and \in symbol.  Can someone tell me what it is?  I dont know how to make TeX display on this page (unlike MathSE).

[image: eee]

Comment: It is an epsilon, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98013/varepsilon-vs-epsilon.

Comment: This is  the *lunate* (or  *uncial*) epsilon and it is obtained  with the `\epsilon` command (in math mode). The usual `ε` is obtained with the `\varepsilon`  command.

Comment: When I copy from that PDF, I got this symbol: ǫ.  Why does it happen?

Comment: tex math fonts use custom font encodings with only 127 characters in each font, placed essentially arbitrarily in different fonts, in the ascii letter positions,  so tex knows that `\epsilon` selects a particular slot in a particular font, but if you take plain text from the pdf, all you have is a numeric number which is then interpreted as a Unicode position so you get a more or less random letter.

Comment: if you want fonts with Unicode values in the output, use lualatex or xelatex and the `unicode-math` package.

Comment: Thank you, David!  Your expert knowledge always enlighten me.

Comment: It does help.  The reason why I posted this question is because I am unsure of the expected answer.  I know epsilon but was unsure if the guess was right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Simply walk across to Detexify -- http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html -- for identifying a symbol

Also see -- [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks!!!  That helps.