# Typesetting \varepsilon (ε) in normal text

Tags: symbols, typography

I have a pretty arcane problem, I know, but here we are:
I reference and cite a project called [*Exodus*](https://reports.exodus-privacy.eu.org/en/) – companies own spelling: εxodus, [i.e.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98018/98645):

[image: logo]

> ε [GREEK SMALL LETTER EPSILON (`\varepsilon`)] + "odus"

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = de_DE
\documentclass[
    fontsize=12pt,
    oneside,
    a4paper,
    titlepage,
    numbers=noenddot,
%   draft,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern} % font <--- may be important
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric,
sortcites=true,
sorting=none,
defernumbers=true,
backref=true,
backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib2.bib}
@online{exodusHomepage,
    title = {$\varepsilon$xodus},
    subtitle = {{varepsilon The privacy audit platform for Android applications}},
    titleaddon = {Startseite},
%   date = {2020-08-29},
    urldate = {2020-08-29},
    language = {english},
    url = {https://reports.exodus-privacy.eu.org/en}
}
@online{exodusHomepageLunar,
    title = {$\epsilon$xodus},
    subtitle = {{epsilon The privacy audit platform for Android applications}},
    titleaddon = {Startseite},
%   date = {2020-08-29},
    urldate = {2020-08-29},
    language = {english},
    url = {https://reports.exodus-privacy.eu.org/en}
}
\end{filecontents} 

\addbibresource{mybib2.bib}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Exodus/exodus:\\
% all commented lines cannot compile or so
% companies own spelling: εxodus\cite{exodusHomepage}\\
% companies own spelling: {\epsilon}xodus\cite{exodusHomepageLunar}\\
% companies own spelling: {\varepsilon}xodus\cite{exodusHomepage}\\
companies own spelling: $\epsilon$xodus\cite{exodusHomepageLunar} (wrong lunar letter actually)\\
companies own spelling: $\varepsilon$xodus\cite{exodusHomepage}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

In the text, it looks I'd say *okay*:
[image]

(Though the `GREEK LUNATE EPSILON SYMBOL` (`\varepsilon`) looks way better IMHO, but well… it's factually/semantically wrong, so I cannot use that.)

But in the bibliography it looks really off though:
[image]

Can we typeset/improve that properly?

Comment: May I respectfully suggest [not following the company's preferred spelling](http://www.theslot.com/webnames.html)?

Comment: Hehe, yeah, you may. But I need to name it bat least once. And also proper citations/references require me to use the original glyphs. :)

Answer (score 10):

Try the textGreek package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\begin{document}
\textepsilon
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer! I added the image for you.

Comment: Indeed great and welcome to this community!
It also works in the "usual" text, but in the bibliography it just fails and throws errors. Here is the example: https://www.overleaf.com/read/dyrpyyrhnkvv

Comment: Also I don't know if this is intended, but your ε goes below the baseline. (test here: \_ε\_ εxodus – it does not do so in my browser here). This would be a strange typography. https://i.imgur.com/e1cFPFh.png

Comment: BTW I've opened this chat room, if we'd need to talk: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/112427/fighting-with-greek-letters--varepsilon?tab=general

Answer (score 8):

Your font might have the Latin small letter epsilon, ɛ (U+025B).

In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you might write something like

```
\newcommand\exodus{{\textepsilon}xodus}
\newcommand\textepsilon{^^^^025b}
```

Or, if you need to load the symbol from another font,

```
\newcommand\textepsilon{{\greekfont ^^^^025b}}
```

You could also use the Greek ε codepoint.

You won’t see anything unless your current font contains the glyph.  The default, Latin Modern Roman, doesn’t have any Greek letters.

You should also add the command `\tracinglostchars=2`.  This will tell you what the problem is.  Without it, TeX will silently log a warning in the log file.

In legacy 8-bit encodings, you might load the text-mode symbol from `textgreek` or `tipa`.

#### MWE

This version works in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Scale=1.0]{CMU Sans Serif}

\newcommand\exodus{{\textepsilon}xodus}
\newcommand\textepsilon{^^^^025b}

\begin{document}
\exodus
\end{document}
```

[image: CMU Sans Serif sample]

And here is a PDFTeX-compatible version

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand\exodus{{\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont\textepsilon}xodus}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\exodus
\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern Sans-Serif sample]

#### ETA: Changing the Font

As requested, here is a version that does not change the main font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\logofont{CMU Sans Serif}[Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures={Common,TeX}]

\newcommand\exodus{{\logofont{\textepsilon}xodus}}
\newcommand\textepsilon{^^^^025b}

\begin{document}
A company named \exodus
\end{document}
```

[image: dejaVu Sans sample]

The legacy version using 8-bit fonts is similar, except that `\logofont` would be defined as something like `\fontfamily{DejaVuSans-TLF}\selectfont`.

Comment: I use UTF-8 encoding, as you can see from my example, but both commands cause compiler errors and it ends up as `025bxodus` in my case. See https://www.overleaf.com/read/dyrpyyrhnkvv
Also the font is `lmodern` as you can see from my example.

Comment: (Okay this error was from `pdflatex`. In `lualatex` it just shows nothing there.)

Comment: BTW I've opened this chat room, if we'd need to talk: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/112427/fighting-with-greek-letters--varepsilon?tab=general

Comment: LuaLaTeX shows nothing there because your font doesn’t contain the symbol. One that does is CMU Serif.

Comment: @rugk I added two MWEs that should make it clearer.

Comment: The LuaLaTex example still does not work. Also, I don't want to change the font globally…

Comment: @rugk It works for me on TeX Live 2020. What error are you getting? I can post a new version that doesn’t change the family.

Comment: Hmm can only tets with TexLIve 2020 and lualatex. Here is a full list of errors: https://www.overleaf.com/read/dyrpyyrhnkvv "Undefined control sequence." for the font already. Okay, maybe it is because I use a KOMA class?

Comment: @rugk It’s because you load `lmodern` instead of `fontspec`, then issue a command from `fontspec`.